# Excel vba to use an existing open website, instead of opening new browser to access the website,

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using an IE browser with Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719015/using-an-ie-browser-with-visual-basic)

I have a website that is updated daily. I need to retrieve the information from this website daily. Instead of opening up a new browser eg new internet explorer everyday, is it possible to use an already opened internet explorer to retrieve the information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE installed so I can't promise this will work, but give it a shot. Note that you'll need to set references to Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library.

```
Function GetOpenIE() As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim sw As SHDocVw.shellWindows

    Set sw = New SHDocVw.shellWindows

    For Each ie In sw
        If TypeOf ie.Document Is HTMLDocument Then
            Set GetOpenIE = ie
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ie

End Function
```

Comment: why post something that you can't test (and presumably should be referenced to a source elsewhere)? Plus as per my comment above this is a duplicate question.